# Orbit Calculations don't seem smooth in pyepehm

Tags: pyephem

I am using pyephem to calculate the position of specific satellites at a specific time.
Doing this using the simple 3LE approach as described here;
http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/quick.html#catalog-format

What I am then doing is writing a loop and adding x minutes to my now() time so that I can get the positions of the satellite in the future - in my mind therefore creating the orbit it will follow.

So using

mySat = ephem.readtle(line1,line2,line3)
mySat.compute(myTime) //MyTime is incremented in each loop by 1 minute.

This gives me a few points but when I plot them they look quite rough which you can see here;
http://cdb.io/1zvJbQX
(ignore the dateline issue).

I think the issue could be a number of problems - so allow me to sanity check;

The output of myDets = mySat.compute are various things but including myDets.sublong and myDets.sublat. These two is what I am using. They come out in the format as 117:34:3.45 which I read as degrees / minutes / seconds, and have converted using D + M/60 + S/3600. 
I think that is right as the positions returned look about right for the satellite in question.

After that - I can only assume that it is the pyephem calculation that is causing this?

I hope that makes sense, if anyone has any pointers as to how I could manage this I'd be very grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have been infected with the 'find the solution once posted online' bug...

Sooo, it seems I wasn't taking negative / positive into account when doing my conversion from DDMMSS to DD.

So below is my code - it's ugly I know.

```
    dmsLong = str(satLine.sublong);
    #print dmsLong
    dmsLat = str(satLine.sublat);
    ddLong = abs(float(dmsLong.split(":")[0]))+(float(dmsLong.split(":")[1])/60)+(float(dmsLong.split(":")[2])/3600)
    ddLat = abs(float(dmsLat.split(":")[0]))+(float(dmsLat.split(":")[1])/60)+(float(dmsLat.split(":")[2])/3600)

    if float(dmsLong.split(":")[0]) < 0:
        ddLong = -ddLong
    if float(dmsLat.split(":")[0]) < 0:
        ddLat = -ddLat
    #print ddLong
    coordstring += "[" + str(ddLong) + "," + str(ddLat) + "],"
```

So that seems to have worked to make the curve smoother.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert values like `sublat` directly to a number by doing math with them:

```
print(satLine.sublat)
print(satLine.sublat / ephem.degree)
```

Output:

```
45:54:58.6
45.9162779596
```